# HDMI/DP to VGA adapers dying

Tags: hdmi, vga, kvm-switch

I have multiple custom built server drawers that have been created in order to test multiple HDD's at once.

All the drawers are connected to a KVM (Tripp-Lite B070-016-19) using the following setup, a HDMI to VGA adapter connected to a Tripp-Lite USB server interface unit into a cat5E cable and finally into the KVM.

The problem I am having is that at least one HDMI to VGA adapter is dying per week. When the adapter fails the KVM screen goes black and unresponsive until you unplug the failed adapters CAT5 cable.

What could be causing these adapter to break ?

Comment: First: I do not know.  Second:  Are the devices dying (hardware error) or just need to be reset?  Is the USB Server supplying incompatible voltage?

Comment: The HDMI to VGA adapter is dying and has to be replaced. I am unsure how I would check if there is an incompatible voltage? The model of the USB interface is (B078-101-usb-1)

Comment: Try a different USB Server Interface.

Comment: I am not sure why I would replace the USB interface as it was sold along with the KVM system ?

Comment: As the manufacturer why the issue with the HDMI adapter.

Comment: Yeah I will do that thanks!